# Error when trying to simulate a Lorenz Attractor

Tags: python, pygame

**I got this from a YouTube video:
The only issue is, when I run the code a window pops up and then instantly closes, then it displays a message in the terminal saying: Process finished with exit code 0.
Can someone help?
This was taken from a video by QuantativeBytes, search up QuantativeBytes on YouTube.**

Code:

```
    import pygame


class LAttractor:

    def __init__(self):
        self.xMin, self.xMax = -30, 30
        self.yMin, self.yMax = -30, 30
        self.zMin, self.zMax = 0, 50
        self.X, self.Y, self.Z = 0.1, 0.0, 0.0
        self.oX, self.oY, self.oZ = self.X, self.Y, self.Z
        self.dt = 0.01
        self.a, self.b, self.c = 10, 28, 8 / 3
        self.pixelColour = (235, 192, 52)

    def step(self):
        self.oX, self.oY, self.oZ = self.X, self.Y, self.Z
        self.X = self.X + (self.dt * self.a * (self.Y - self.X))
        self.Y = self.Y + (self.dt * (self.X * (self.b - self.Z) - self.Y))
        self.Z = self.Z + (self.dt * (self.X * self.Y - self.c * self.Z))

    def draw(self, displaySurface):
        width, height = displaySurface.get_size()
        oldPos = self.ConvertToScreen(self.oX, self.oY, self.xMin, self.xMax, self.yMin, self.yMax, width, height)
        newPos = self.ConvertToScreen(self.X, self.Y, self.xMin, self.xMax, self.yMin, self.yMax, width, height)

        # Draw the active line segment:
        newRect = pygame.draw.line(displaySurface, self.pixelColour, oldPos, newPos, 2)

        # Return the bounding rect:
        return newRect

    def ConvertToScreen(self, x, y, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, width, height):
        newX = width * ((x - xMin) / (xMax - width))
        newY = height * ((y - yMin) / (yMax - height))
        return round(newX), round(newY)


class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.isRunning = True
        self.displaySurface = None
        self.fpsClock = None
        self.attractors = []
        self.size = self.width, self.height = 1920, 1080
        self.count = 0
        self.outputCount = 1

    def on_init(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Lorenz Attractor Simulation")
        self.displaySurface = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)
        self.isRunning = True
        self.fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

        # Configure the attractor
        self.attractors = LAttractor()

    def on_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.isRunning = False

    def on_loop(self):
        # Call the step method for the attractor
        self.attractors.step()

    def on_render(self):
        # Draw the attractor
        newRect = self.attractors.draw(self.displaySurface)
        pygame.display.update(newRect)

    def on_execute(self):
        if self.on_init() == False:
            self.isRunning = False

            while self.isRunning:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    self.on_event(event)

                self.on_loop()
                self.on_render()

                self.fpsClock.tick()
                self.count += 1

            pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Application()
    q.on_execute()
```

Comment: Your while loop is inside your `if` block, which would mean that `self.isRunning` is `False`, and that the loop won't run

Comment: I changed the last part to this:

    def on_execute(self):
        if self.on_init() == False:
            self.isRunning = False

        while self.isRunning:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                self.on_event(event)

            self.on_loop()
            self.on_render()

            self.fpsClock.tick()
            self.count += 1

            pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Application()
    q.on_execute()

Comment: But it still quits

Comment: It says "for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized"

Comment: I fixed the video system issue by changing the if statement to if not self.on_init():, but then it still crashes

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). Also `on_init` should return `True`:

```py
class Application:
    # [...]

    def on_init(self):
        # [...]

        # Configure the attractor
        self.attractors = LAttractor()

        return True

    # [...]

    def on_execute(self):
        if self.on_init() == False:
            self.isRunning = False

            #INDENTATION
        #<--|
        while self.isRunning:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                self.on_event(event)

            self.on_loop()
            self.on_render()

            self.fpsClock.tick()
            self.count += 1

        pygame.quit()
```